# Getting this 'Undefined method 'fetch''

Tags: ruby, undefined

I am learning ruby and getting this error

My code:

```
class New_class
  hash{}
  File.readlines('file.txt').each do |line|
    if (line =~ /^(\w+)=>(.*)/)
      hash[$1] =$2
    end
  end

  def check
    a='2345'
    value = hash.fetch{a,''}
    if (value == '')
      puts 'Error no value found'
    else
      puts value
    end
  end
end

var=New_class.new
var.check
```

Error :`undefined method 'fetch'`

Here I want `hash` to run one time and store all the key/value so that I can use the hash in multiple methods and check for values. Anyone know how to fix this error or any better way to do?

Answer (score 2):

The `hash` variable is out of scope. You can make it global by changing it to `$hash`.
Also `fetch` uses round brackets not curly brackets.

```
class New_class
  $hash = {}
  File.readlines('file.txt').each do |line|
    if (line =~ /^(\w+)=>(.*)/)
      $hash[$1] =$2
    end
  end

  def check
    a='2345'
    value = $hash.fetch(a,'')
    if (value == '')
      puts 'Error no value found'
    else
      puts value
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: A few comments: 1) the class name `New_class` is not idiomatic. Classes should be defined in PascalCase. 2) global variable is a bad idea. Its location inside "New_class" has no bearing because it is "global" instead use a constant or a class instance variable. 3) `hash` is a bad name for a variable as it lacks context and depending on its usage it could hide the `Object#hash` method.